# Signal handling in shell script

Tags: shell, operating-system, signals

I want processes to be blocked for a custom user signal and when the signal arrives it should wake up waiting process in shell script?need just steps coding i can take care of?

Comment: The command you need is `trap`. This is a shell builtin command. Search for "shell trap signal" to find lots of tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

If the signal you wish to send is signal number 17, then you might use:

```
trap ":" 17
sleep 1000000
trap 17
# ...what you want to happen after the signal is received...
```

The first `trap` command will execute the quoted command (`:`) when the signal is received.  The `:` command does nothing.  However, you can't use `trap "" 17` as that means 'ignore signal 17', which is the opposite of what you want.

The `sleep 1000000` is a way to do nothing for a long time without using up CPU resource.

The second `trap` cancels the signal handling for signal 17, reinstating the default behaviour.

After that, you can put whatever code you want executed once the signal is received.

---

Instead of using `sleep`, you might prefer to create and use a program, `pause`, which waits indefinitely (rather than risk the `sleep` waking up before the signal is received).  You could use this trivial program:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    pause();
    return(0);
}
```

As a point of detail, the return won't usually be executed; the signal will usually force the program to terminate before `pause()` returns with `errno == EINTR`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you basically want a shell-scrip "keylogger" to listen in the background and take action based on things. If I'm correct, I'm not going to ask why... if I'm not I apologise ;-)

If you want to go hardcore you could learn about the /dev/input/event* files in the filesystem and how to follow them. Alternatively you could look at this tutorial for creating a keylogger and loggin:
http://www.slideshare.net/rmorrill/creating-a-keystroke-logger-in-unix-shell-scripting

Finally, if you really do just want to install and go you could try installing this:
http://www.justhackitnow.com/2012/03/keylogger-for-linux.html